# What is the probability of excatly two out of three events happening?

Tags: probability

I'm started working on probabilities and now I'm facing two problems.

So I have 3 independent events, p1 = 0,90, p2 = 0,65, p3 = 0,90;

I calculated probability when **all events occur**: **P(p1 ∩ p2 ∩ p3)** = P(p1) * P(p2) * P(p3) = 0,9 * 0,65 * 0,9 = **0,5265;**

Then I calculated probability when **at least one** event occurs: P(p1) + P(p2) + P(p3) - P(p1 ∩ p2) - P(p1 ∩ p3) - P(p2 ∩ p3) + P(p1 ∩ p2 ∩ p3) = 0,9 + 0,65 + 0,9 – 0,585 – 0,81 – 0,585 + 0,5265 = **0,9965;**

Also I have calculated probability when **none of the events occur** - **0,0035**

Now I need to calculate:

1. Probability when **exactly two out of three** events occur.
2. At least one event **NOT** happening.

Waiting for yours suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability of first and second event occuring but third one not occuring is is $p_1p_2(1-p_3)$, that of second and third  events occuring but not the first one  is $p_2p_3(1-p_1)$  and that of first and third  events occuring but not the second one is  is $p_2p_3(1-p_2)$. Add these to get the probability of exactly two events occuring.

Probability of at least one event happening is just $1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$.

Comment: Thank you! But whats about when at least one event NOT happening?

Comment: @KarolisKazlauskas The probability that at least one event does not occur is $1$ minus the probability that all three events occur.

Comment: Thanks you for your helpful and fast answer! Have a nice day!

Comment: @KarolisKazlauskas Telling you this since you're a new user: Please "accept" the answer if it indeed answers your question.

Comment: Have a look at probability trees. They are often useful to reveal all the possibilities for events in situations like yours and orient the computation of asked probabilities.